# Coinmarketcap api blocked by Adblock

Tags: reactjs, api

I have made a react app few months ago. It's a simple app that utilizes Coinmarketcap api to list prices for different cryptocurrencies. When I tried to check on it later, I found out that adblock block the api URL.
How do I make sure this doesn't happen on the user client, and why is this happing in the first place?

Comment: You can't. The API URL that is blocked is not under your control. A solution would be to proxy that API through a different URL that is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way would be to set up a custom API that acts as a proxy (you could use Firebase functions/ AWS Lambda/ Stdlib), unless Coinmarketcap has a secondary API which isn't blocked.